# Node.js Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function in process.nextTick

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I'm getting the following error. It's clearly coming from a callback passed to `process.nextTick`. Given that the stack trace is virtually unusable, how do I debug this? What's going on behind the scenes, and how can I resolve this in a larger project?

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:390:13)
```

N.B. Older versions of Node had a different implementation of `process.nextTick`, and spit out the following stack trace.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node.js tick callback prefers to throw an error if the function you pass to `process.nextTick` is not a function after a tick has passed, rather than telling you when you first call it.

Where a function will just get called after a tick:

```
// this will print "hi!", followed by "hello there"
process.nextTick(function() {
  console.log('hello there');
});
console.log('hi!');
```

A non-function won't actually matter until the next tick:

```
// this will just print "hi!", and an error will be thrown later on
process.nextTick(undefined);
console.log('hi!');
```

Below, I'll outline two diagnostic tools you can use to track down the culprit.

#### Tool 1: `longjohn`

As it turns out, this kind of scenario is common enough that a tool exists to extend stack traces with information from previous ticks.

Simply install [longjohn](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn) (available [on npm](http://npmjs.com/longjohn)), and `require` it when your process starts. This will yield a stack trace similar to the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
---------------------------------------------
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../example.js:3:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

Now that you have a useful stack trace, you can use your debugging skills to figure out why you're giving `process.nextTick` undefined rather than a function.

#### Monkey patching

Because javascript is dynamic, we can easily setup a new version of `process.nextTick` (that is, we can [monkey patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) it) which traces the call to it, but proxies to the real nextTick function:

```
var nextTick = process.nextTick;

process.nextTick = function(callback) {
  if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
    console.trace(typeof callback + ' is not a function');
  }
  return nextTick.apply(process, arguments);
};
```

*Note:* I don't recommend doing this for production code, but it does make it much easier to locate where you're providing something besides a function to `process.nextTick`. Remember that this is modifying the global `process` variable, so it might break at some point and it's certainly not considered best practice, but it'll do nicely for finding small problems. (Addendum: and since I originally wrote this post, I've had to revise it because it broke once.)

```
Trace: undefined is not a function
    at process.nextTick (.../example.js:5:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../example.js:10:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

As above, now that you have a useful stack trace, you can identify the root cause.

In terms of the internals, check out the `_tickCallback` function in `node.js` in [the source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.3.1/lib/internal/process/next_tick.js#L87) ([old link](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.24/src/node.js#L393)).

Comment: Nice answer and clear, Thanks just a little sugest you should be include the word "_tickCallback" or "nextTick" at the title at the question if you can

Comment: Good idea, thanks! I might also add a link to longjohn - it's a more versatile tool